# Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric. Tried convert and replace

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes, algebraic-data-types

I am trying to add a sum of my forecast using a code

```
select 
    sum(cast(replace(replace(ZFREEGOOD, ',', ''), ' ', '') as decimal(22,8))) 
from 
    TEMP_GBR_History_1611
```

I keep getting an error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

I used a case statement to figure out which rows failed. These are some of them

Would be of great help to get a solution

[image]

Comment: Images of data isn't helpful for debugging a problem with `text`, as we can't do the one thing we **need** to do with it; inspect the text . Post your sample data as text. Also, when you edit it, please the results of the following query: `SELECT ZFREEGOOD
FROM {YourTable}
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(decimal(22,8),REPLACE(REPLACE(ZFREEGOOD,',',''),' ','')) IS NULL;` (Again, as `text`).

Comment: The issue is that an empty string is considered as invalid cast to decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not handling the blank case, this works with test data:

```
select sum(cast(case when replace(replace(ZFREEGOOD,',',''),' ','') = '' then '0' else replace(replace(ZFREEGOOD,',',''),' ','') end as decimal(22,8))) from TEMP_GBR_History_1611
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `try_convert(money,...)`  It tends to be a little more forgiving.

**Example**

```
Select AsMoney = try_convert(money,' 27,300')   -- works!
      ,AsInt   = try_convert(int,' 27,300')
      ,AsDec   = try_convert(decimal(10,2),' 27,300')
      ,AsFloat = try_convert(float,' 27,300')
```

**Returns**

```
AsMoney     AsInt   AsDec   AsFloat
27300.00    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: I tried this method. But it ignores the value when it fails to convert.

Comment: @RifadhZizou try_convert() will return a NULL if the conversion fails.  This is helpful in finding the "problem" data     You can wrap it in an IsNull( ... , 0)